# satellite CL45-C4330 No wifi adapters found error

Tags: broadcom

My Toshiba Satellite CL45-C4330's (This laptop model doesn't have a ethernet port to use so bare that in mind.) Wi-fi isn't working not just that but nor is the bluetooth. I can't even use USB tethering from my phone!

I've looked around most already solved threads all required ethernet.

It's a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and I have verified that the wireless card is recognized but is not working, the card being: *broadcom limited BCM43143 802.11b/g/n*

Under 'additional drivers' I have "using broadcom 802.11linux sta wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source(open source)" ticked.

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: _"Modprobe: FATAL: Module w1 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic"_  does this speak to you?

Comment: That's `wl`, not `w1`.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was inaccurate? I'm using my Android to post here. But that was the result I got. But the 1 is the same as the command. I'm physically typing out rather than copy and paste

Comment: Please confirm that you entered wl with a lower-case L and not w1 with the numeral One.

Comment: I entered the following:"_sudo modprobe wl_" if that's correct it returned the following:"_modprobe:  FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic_" I made sure it was with a lower case L and also not a 1 , it appears to be the same?

Comment: I've done more extensive research and found the having secure boot enabled may have something to do with that error message?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The problem was secure boot!

I thank you chili555! you pointed me in the right direction!

I read one of your responses to another person with a similar problem did another reinstall w/ secure boot off and it worked!

How does one mark a thread as solved?